# Email is not receiving when current domain name is sent in email body

Tags: php, email, codeigniter-3

Hy everyone.I am facing strange issue in Simple Php Mail function.I am using codeignitor framework and using Default email library to send emails.Here is my code

```
$subject = "Become a Member of Room";
$message = "Hi Zeeshan";
$message.= "<a href='http://iqra.com.hk/sms/Member/activate/sdskdksn2n23kan92nns29/12'>Clickhere</a>";
$message.= "Room Invite is here";
$message.= "Regards,<br><br>";
$message.= "Demo School";
$this->sendEmail('myemail@gmail.com', $subject, $message,'Demo School');
```

Defination of sendEmail() Function

```
 function sendEmail($email,$subject,$message,$school){
    $this->load->library('email');
    $config['protocol'] = 'sendmail';
    $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
    $config['mailpath'] = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
    $config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
    $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
    $this->email->initialize($config);
    $this->email->from('no-reply@example.com',$school);
    $this->email->to($email);
    $this->email->subject($subject);
    $this->email->message($message);
    $this->email->send();

}
```

Now i am facing issue is that when  i send email,email doesn't received.I tracked this issue and i find that **http://iqra.com.hk/sms/** in Link is creating issue.When i remove **http://iqra.com.hk/sms/** from

```
$message.= "<a href='http://iqra.com.hk/sms/Member/activate/sdskdksn2n23kan92nns29/12'>Clickhere</a>";
```

and make it like this

```
$message.= "<a href='Member/activate/sdskdksn2n23kan92nns29/12'>Clickhere</a>";
```

then email receives.So i am wondering Why email is not receiving by adding my domain name in Link?Please suggest me.

Comment: Well that would most likely be the spam filter on the receiving end ... maybe Google doesn’t like that domain, thinks it is malware/spam ...

Comment: just because email is sent doesn't mean it's received. In fact probably about 80% of the process is out of your hands. I'd say the same, probably a spam filter. Not a great idea putting your real email addresses on the net btw, I guess now they'll get a lot more spam too.